# microseconds to day month year

Tags: php, database, time

I am trying to utilize a database with timestamps listed in a cryptic format to convert to day:month:year:hours:minutes:seconds

I know what the end product of each string of digits is, I need to know the process so I can convert the number to the desired format in php. I'm basically trying to reverse engineer this.

Here is a sample set of my data:

- 1382400446259 = 10/21/13 8:04PM est
- 1382400506245 = 10/21/13 8:05PM est
- 1382400746341 = 10/21/13 8:09PM est
- 1382401975092 = 10/21/13 8:10PM est
- 1382402068713 = 10/21/13 8:29PM est

from what i can tell based off this info,

1 minute = 60,000 units of this string of digits.

I tried dividing the number by 60000, then by 60, then by 24, then by 365 to get th number in a yearly format, but i get roughly 43 years. nothing like my desired output

any insight would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [Unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in milliseconds. That is, the number of milliseconds since 12:00:00 AM January 1, 1970 UTC.

I think this code will do what you want:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$date = date('d:m:Y:H:i:s', 1382400446259 / 1000);

var_dump($date);
```

It will give you this:

```
string(19) "21:10:2013:20:07:26"
```

Check out the [page from the PHP manual on the `date()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more info on the different formats.

Comment: thanks, that worked great. not sure why I hadn't done this already. I was confused about the 43 years, however it makes perfect sense based off of 1970.